# My Amazon Web Service instance won't boot: Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: linux, boot, centos, amazon-web-services, centos-6

My AWS instance won't boot. I logged into the control panel and select Action > Instance > Get System Log. Here is the log, but I don't understand it. What failed?

https://pastebin.com/rSxr1kLs

It's using CentOS.

Comment: See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=255240

Comment: OK but that doesn't help. The instance still won't boot. I can't edit files if the instance won't boot. There is also this documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html